# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given these types:

```
export type ButtonProps = {
    kind?: 'normal' | 'flat' | 'primary';
    negative?: boolean;
    size?: 'small' | 'big';
    spinner?: boolean;
}

export type LinkButtonPropsExtended = ButtonProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>;

const LinkButton = ({ children, href, ...rest }: LinkButtonPropsExtended) => (
    <a href={href} className={cls(rest)}>
        { children }
    </a>
);
```

How come this use case:

```
<LinkButton href={url} size="big">My button</LinkButton>
```

Throws this type error:

```sh
64:53 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
    63 |                 <Button size="big">Another button<Button>
  > 64 |                 <LinkButton href={url} size="big">My button</LinkButton>
       |                                        ^
```

Is the Typescript compiler interpreting the `size` prop to be of type `undefined`? Why?

Comment: Please, provide `typescript` version. I will try to reproduce this in a sandbox.

Comment: And what is `cls`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that `React.HTMLProps` already has `size` property which is declared as following:

```
size?: number
```

This causes `size` type to be `undefined`. Here is example [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCBXAzjCBbOAXjgG8AoOSuLASwC9gB%20ALjgHIs8BDAGx7bgAfdgCMaAczYBuMgF8yZUJFgJkqAErAuAYxgAVNUVIUqtBizgA7DHhHAochUujwkKOACkINS0cw58OAAyOE0dfTUZbQhLHDgQVi8fI3IqanpgVjYxSTkgA), where you can see how is type resolved to `undefined`.

Your best bet is to change name of your `size` property or omit `HTMLProps` `size` property, for example:

```
type MyHTMLProps = Omit<React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>, 'size'>;
export type LinkButtonPropsExtended = ButtonProps & MyHTMLProps;
```

Comment: Cheers! Didn't know about `Omit` before. Will definitely be using that a lot!

Comment: Here is a bunch of utility types that might be of good use: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html