# TypeScript cannot assign to optional property "is not assignable to type undefined"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here is a minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue:

```
const map = {
  FOO: 'foo',
  BAR: 'bar',
} as const

export const CSV_COLUMNS_ALL = Object.values(map)

export type ColumnName = typeof CSV_COLUMNS_ALL[number]

export type RowField<CN extends ColumnName> = {
  /** The Original value from the CSV file */
  original: string
  /** The row index for the csv row that this field belongs to */
  rowIndex: number
  /** The header text in the CSV for this column of data */
  columnName: CN
}

export type CsvRow = {
  [k in ColumnName]?: RowField<k>
} & {
  index: number
}

const row:CsvRow = CSV_COLUMNS_ALL.reduce((row, columnName) => {
  row[columnName] = { columnName, original: '', rowIndex: 1 }
  return row
}, { index: 1 } as CsvRow)
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4wLwwN4FgBQMYBiA8kQFwwDkAZiCBQDS74BCAggErkUBGCATg1wBfGAggxQkKLlwBTAB5IQfWJOgwAwgGUAagH0NRADIBVALIA5LXtZGjaGEW4ArWcCgA6AG4IANgFdZCAAKRCQAShkcBSUVGCgATyRZTRAAuDALBDgU9ETkkCpNXQNjcysbOwBtMH84blk+AF0omOVYfJT2EAB3AgBLWV8AEwAeDQsYBShZMGHxDTS6zOzZAD4HbDwYAHoAKj2YABUACxSiPn6Ac36wPxgfAJSqPhA4eLPinRgqft8UvY7JgwZTXW5+cjQS5gK7A-aHU4pV49GC3YYKH7KD4pYAQLwwZEfBAdE79cS-IbDGANXzgK7iKAgGCA4HIgCScwU5Fq9UacIOx0+ZwQ6L48WmqLA2K+mLFUFJ4lA6SlhRgw2JCGZQO2SuWWRy5Amwlaina8SSKQ0eO6KPQW3wVQA1pLUsr9bImgB+cg2gaU0aOtbCGAAMkwwLRXJgPIafGNOFwalgyNIVq8Noc2n0hlMlmstiMHj4smG-mAsmCwWR9AkSwy7vCaA29oJvSquvrqyam1rbtWNdBNzuvi4DFbPQ56Pk5AAjDAhLhi1B-HwpcjhDWMJKp7P56IFtbeuEgA)

The line in question is this one:

```
row[columnName] = { columnName, original: '', rowIndex: 1 }
```

It's basically telling me that I cannot assign this value to type 'undefined'

However `row` is of type `CsvRow` and `columnName` is of type `ColumnName` and that should be an assignable property with an optional type of `RowField<ColumnName>` which this satisfies.

So why is it stopping me, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't yet figure out the problem, but i have a suggestion for another way to do it which seems to be working fine with typescript:

```
row = {...row, [columnName]: { columnName, original: '', rowIndex: 1 }}
```

Basically spread the `row` parameter object and add the new property. save it all in the `row` parameter.

Check it out in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4wLwwN4FgBQMYBiA8kQFwwDkAZiCBQDS74BCAggErkUBGCATg1wBfGAggxQkKLlwBTAB5IQfWJOgwAwgGUAagH0NRADIBVALIA5LXtZGjaGEW4ArWcCgA6AG4IANgFdZCAAKRCQAShkcBSUVGCgATyRZTRAAuDALBDgU9ETkkCpNXQNjcysbOwBtMH84blk%20AF0omOVYfJT2EAB3AgBLWV8AEwAeDQsYBShZMGHxDTS6zOzZAD4HbDwYAHoAKj2YABUACxSiPn6Ac36wPxgfAJSqPhA4eLPinRgqft8UvY7JgwZTXW5%20cjQS5gK7A-aHU4pV49GC3YYKH7KD4pYAQLwwZEfBAdE79cS-IbDGANXzgK7iKAgGCA4HIgCScwU5Fq9UacIOx0%20ZwQ6L48WmqLA2K%20mLFUFJ4lA6SlhRgw2JCGZQO2SuWWRy5Amwlaina8SSKQ0eO6KPQW3wVQA1pLUsr9bImgB%20cg2gaU0aOtbCGAAMkwwLRXJgPIafGNOFwalgyNIVq8Noc2n0hlMlmstiMHj4smG-mAsmCwWR9AkSwy7vCaA29oJvU2Hg71ZgVV19dWTXIGFrbtWNdBNzuvi4DFbPQ56Pk5AAjDAhEJcMWoP4%20FLkcIa0PI4uYCuRGJNNbeuEgA)

Comment: Yeah I think the issue is that when I start the reduce function, with `{ index: 1 } as CsvRow` it locks the generic param is undefined, so I can no longer assign to it. I think work around might be the best way to a reset what the generic param is.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another suggestion is to ungenerify RowField type, that makes the error go away, check out [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4wLwwN4FgBQMYBiA8kQFwwDkAZiCBQDS74BCAggErkUBGCATg1wBfGAggxQkKLlwBTAB5IQfWJOgwAwgGUAagH0NRADIBVALIA5LXtZGjaGEW4ArWcCgA6AG4IANgFdZCAAKRCQAShkcBSUVGCgATyRZTRAAuDALBDgU9ETkkCpNXQNjcysbOwBtMH84blk%20AF0omOVYfJT2EAB3AgBLWV8AEwdsPBgAegAqaZgAFQALFKI%20foBzfrA-GB8AlKo%20EDh45eKdGCp%203xTpyaYYZQ2tv3JoNbB1h5m5pZSjnowLbDBSXZSnFLACBeGAA04IDqLfriK5DUYNXzgdbiKAgGB3B4AgCSYBB8nItXqjW%20swWZ2WCBBfHiClgWwh5zBzKgSPEoHSYEeRWGCIQ%20PuE35dUy2Vk5A0aWlWRywlaina8SSKQ00O6gPQ43wVQA1kDBQqBcrZE0APzkPUDNHCGAAMkwD2BCgpdQafFVOFwalgANIOq8eoc2n0hlMlmstiMHj4smG-mAsmCwQB9AkioyVvCaAAfO6JgCqlL87KmmNc5bZTmnpttr4uAxYb0SWTyABGGAiADcuGTUH8fEFAOEOYwZu7MD7IjEml1vXCQA).

```
const map = {
  FOO: 'foo',
  BAR: 'bar',
} as const

export const CSV_COLUMNS_ALL = Object.values(map)

export type ColumnName = typeof CSV_COLUMNS_ALL[number]

export type RowField = {
  /** The Original value from the CSV file */
  original: string
  /** The row index for the csv row that this field belongs to */
  rowIndex: number
  /** The header text in the CSV for this column of data */
  columnName: ColumnName
}

export type CsvRow = {
  [k in ColumnName]?: RowField
} & {
  index: number
}

const row:CsvRow = CSV_COLUMNS_ALL.reduce((row, columnName) => {
  row[columnName] = { columnName, original: '', rowIndex: 1 } ;
return row
}, { index: 1 } as CsvRow)
```

Can't figure out the reason why this is happening, found another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679634/type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-undefined) that suggests a clash of properties. Maybe more seasoned developers can explain what is going on here.